# arraylist not printing correct data

Tags: java, arraylist

Trying to return highest score but it is returning the wrong score...not sure what the issue is, if I am setting the first object in the arraylist to the highest score and then comparing it to that?

```
public String findHighest () {
Student newStu;
Student s;

int highest;
s=collegeList.get(0);
highest=s.getQuizScore();

for (int i=1; i<collegeList.size() ;i++ ) {

    newStu=collegeList.get(i);

    if (highest>newStu.getQuizScore()){
        highest=newStu.getQuizScore();
        return newStu.toString();
    }

}
```

}

---

```
public String findHighest () {
    Student newStu;
    Student s;

    int highest;
    s=collegeList.get(0);
    highest=s.getQuizScore();

    for (int i = 1; i < collegeList.size(); i++) {
        newStu = collegeList.get(i);

        if (highest < newStu.getQuizScore()){
            highest = newStu.getQuizScore();

        }

    }

    return newStu.toString();
}
```

//tried this and it keeps saying newStu may not have been intiailized...

Comment: Here's an idea.  Sort the list based on the scores and pop the last one (or first one based on the sort order) :P

Answer (score 2):

Your condition seems to be reversed:

```
if (highest>newStu.getQuizScore()){
```

change it to:

```
if (highest<newStu.getQuizScore()){
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few approaches to this.

The first, and most direct approach is to fix the logic error:  **the largest element you find at *this* moment is returned.**  The inequality is also reversed.

Change this to:

```
for (int i = 1; i < collegeList.size(); i++) {
    newStu = collegeList.get(i);

    if (highest < newStu.getQuizScore()){
        highest = newStu.getQuizScore();
    }

}
return newStu.toString();
```

Note that the inequality has flipped to reflect that, if `highest` is actually less than some student's quiz score, then we've found a new highest.

**Finding a new highest does not guarantee we've found *the* highest.**  We have to continue iterating through until we're certain.

Another approach would be to use a `SortedSet<Student>`, and have `Student` implement `Comparable`, so that when one inserts values into the set, they're automatically ordered by their grades.

That declaration would look like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student other) {
    if(other == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(quizScore == other.getQuizScore()) {
        return 0;
    }

    if(quizScore < other.getQuizScore()) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

...then, you construct your `TreeSet<Student>` thusly:

```
SortedSet<Student> orderedStudents = new TreeSet<>();
```

...and you can place the elements into this set like you would your list.  Your largest element now lives at the **end** of the set, and can be accessed with a simple `last()` call.

Comment: keeps giving me an error saying variable newStu might have not been initialized...

Comment: ...So initialize it to null.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to start the index of the for-loop at 0. Then you should put your return after the loop because the loop will automatically stop when the return is reached.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the first highest score in the iteration.

```
if (highest>newStu.getQuizScore()){ //here the comparison problem
    highest=newStu.getQuizScore();
    return newStu.toString();   // here returning the first highest score in the iteration.
}
```

Try below code

```
public String findHighest () {
   Student newStu;
   Student s;

   int highest;
   s=collegeList.get(0);
   highest=s.getQuizScore();

   for (int i=1; i<collegeList.size() ;i++ ) {

      f (highest<collegeList.get(i)){
          highest=newStu.getQuizScore();
          newStu=collegeList.get(i)

      }

  }
  return newStu.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop should be like this :

```
for (int i=1; i<collegeList.size() ;i++ ) {

newStu=collegeList.get(i);

    if (highest<newStu.getQuizScore()){
        highest=newStu.getQuizScore();
    }

}
return newStu.toString(); //return the value after for loop
```